# i want to add an object to the linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have class and i want to put the object of this class in a linked list 
And here is the code.
And is there any way to make any object created to be in the linked list automatically ?
 `

```
    public class LibraryUser {
    protected String user;
    protected int password;
    protected String email;
    protected String category;
    protected int count = 0;
    public LibraryUser()
    {
        count ++;
    }

    public String getUser() {

        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user + count;
    }

    public int getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(int password) {

        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
`
```

Comment: where is your linkedlist? are you going to implement one or use linkedlist api?

Comment: I will use the api , and it will be inside the class.

Comment: can you be more specific about what your issue is ?

Comment: i want to know how to implement the linked list using objects of this class

Comment: You mean you want to have a static LinkedList within the class itself?

Comment: it dont have to be static , but yes it would be in the class itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the linkedlist first, then add to it in the constructor.

```
public static LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

public LibraryUser() {
    count ++;
    // add to the list
    list.add(this);
}
```

Comment: "    list.add(this);
" means that every object is created it will be added to the linkedlist automatically right ?

Comment: Yes. list.add(this) means: "Add this LibraryUser object to the static linkedlist called list in my class"

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a static LinkedList object within the class (it needs to be static otherwise each instance would have a separate LinkedList with only that object in the List.)

Inside the class constructor you would then have the object get added to the LinkedList (Off the top of my head I would imagine you could use the `this` keyword to do it)

Comment: @OmarMokhtar I dont see where you have a linked list. You would need to put that code in too for me to be able to help you further.

Comment: it will be in the same class , i dont know yet where is the best place to make it , so if you dont mind to help me in that